# Disable xDebug on phpMyAdmin

Tags: xampp, phpstorm, xdebug

I am using xDebug for a first time. Everything works well, but when I want to go on `localhost/phpmyadmin` it want to start debug (I don't have breakpoints here).

How can I disable it only for phpmyadmin?

My config:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.collect_return="0"
```

I am using XAMPP, PhpStorm.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just turn off the debug connection listener by going to `Run > Stop Listening for PHP Debug Connections`.

PHPStorm will then ignore any connections from Xdebug. When you want to debug something again simply go to `Run > Start Listening for PHP Debug Connections` and it'll work again.

You could also permanently ignore those files by using **Skipped Paths**:

- Go to Preferences
- Go to Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Debug > Skipped Paths
- Click the '+' sign to open a browse dialog
- Browse to the web root where the `phpmyadmin` folder is located and select that folder
- Click OK and exit out of preferences

The debugger should now ignore scripts in that directory.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, i try this and it works good, but is there any configuration, which do it automaticly on phpmyadmin?

Comment: Check my edit, I've added about skipped paths which may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks it works, but now it loading page 10s it si 5x slower. Is there any configuration or sometnig which slow my request on localhost/phpmyadmin?

Comment: The only thing I can think of that could kill performance would be the xdebug profiler, although it's worth a try giving everything a reboot i.e. apache and see if that helps.

Comment: it works, only when i accessing phpmyadmin for a first time, i don't know why, but when i want access page for a second time, i must wait longer(from 2s on 10s) i will be using your first advice. Thanks :)

Comment: I think you should also disable `Force break at first line when no path mapping specified` and `Force break at first line when a script is outside the project`