# PHP debugging stops my localhost connection

Tags: localhost, phpstorm, xdebug

I installed PhpStorm and my debugging (Xdebug) in it. I use XAMPP 7.4.1.

It works well, but I have the problem, that if I click on "Start Listening for php debug connections" then my connection to localhost (and PhpMyAdmin) does not work any more. After stopping the "Listening" the connection to localhost works fine again.

Is there a way to connect localhost while debugging process?

Comment: Sounds like it is connecting just fine. Make a log by setting in php.ini: xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.org, and then tail -f /tmp/xdebug.org it to see what happens on the wire.

Comment: Collect and provide Xdebug log + post your Xdebug settings (Xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output captured via browser)

Comment: What were you expecting? Do you see that IDE is trying to accept an incoming debugging connection when you're loading localhost sites?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found two similar questions that may be useful to solve it. You can either:

1. **Ignore** debugging on phpmyadmin files by using **Skipped Paths** ([Disable xDebug on phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38634665/disable-xdebug-on-phpmyadmin/38634734#38634734))
2. **Disable** the several '**force break at the first line**...' checks in order to don't start debugging until phpStorm finds a breakpoint in your code ([How to stop xdebug from stopping on first line with PhpStorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114762/how-to-stop-xdebug-from-stopping-on-first-line-with-phpstorm/19185093#19185093))

I hope the answers that I have referenced help you.